# Прекращение цикла после ввода пустого input

Tags: python-3.x, input, while

Есть задача:
цикл который дожен выполнятся до тех пор, пока я не нажму Enter, т.е. не введу пустой input, типо `while input():` но это прерывает цикл + надо вводить каждый раз значение.
Идей нету.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1

while a:
    a = input('Вводите что-нибудь, выход `Enter`')
```